# problem of make table in the center

Tags: tables

I am new in LaTeX; I want make table in the center of page please.

[image]

The code used is:

```
    \begin{landscape}
        \centering
        \begin{table}[h]
            \centering
            
    
    
    
    \label{tab:\thetable}
\end{table} 

        
    \end{landscape}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1):

- You not provide any information about your document, so you left us to guessing what you have in landscape page.
- Only one table?
- If this is a case, than for table positioning use `[p]`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small,
            labelfont=bf, 
            ]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[p]   % <------
\caption{Caption} 
\label{tab:?}    
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \lipsum[1] &   \lipsum[2]   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]